# how to update the image in table view cell using core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am  picking image from local device gallery using image picker but the image is not getting saved and displayed in the table view cell once the gallery gets dismissed using core data using xcode 7.3 ,ios9 and swift 2.2

```
 if isUpdate == true{
            print("object id \(self.store?.objectID)")
            self.store?.sName = name.text
            self.store?.sDescription = desc.text
            //save.setTitle("my text here", forState: .Normal)
            let img = UIImage(named: "image.jpeg")
            let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!,1)
            self.store?.sImage = imgData
            do {
                try appdelegate.managedObjectContext.save()
                self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }

        }else{
            //get the description of the entity
            let storeDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Store",inManagedObjectContext: appdelegate.managedObjectContext)

            //we create managed object to be inserted to core data
            let store = EventsandnotesStore(entity : storeDescription!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext:appdelegate.managedObjectContext)
            store.sName = name.text
            store.sDescription = desc.text
            //
            let img = UIImage(named: "image.jpeg")

            let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img!,1)

            store.sImage = imgData
            do {
                try appdelegate.managedObjectContext.save()
                self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }

          }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't mention issues with the Name and Description fields or the creation of the store object, I'm assuming that all worked and you're OK with the CoreData process.

One thing to check is the integer value 1 in the JPEG conversion call.  That should be a Float so try 1.0 in the call, though I'm surprised that didn't get caught by XCode. Not sure whether that could cause your issue.

The other potential issue you may have with the conversion that I've bumped up against is that the UIImageJPEGRepresentation call can fail for other reasons, returning a nil value (e.g., this happened when I converted a CIImage directly to a UIImage, but it worked if I did it via a CGImage - go figure).  Given all that, you should check the result of the call. I use a guard statement and custom logger as follows:

```
    guard let thumbnailData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnailUI, Set.shared.jpegQuality) else
    {
        logError(#file, line: #line, column: #column, function: #function, description: "JPG Conversion Error - thumbnail")
        return nil
    }
```

If that's failing you'll need to check on the images you're getting from the picker.

If you are having problems with the database side of things, have you included the TableView delegate functions in your view controller (controllerWillChangeContent, etc.).  You'll need these so that your configureCell method gets called when the record with the image changes.

Those are the things I'd start with.

Comment: I accidentally gave same name to different images, got it fixed by using logError.